# Why might I get a "Service cannot initialize" error in my console when a plist file is run?

Tags: macos, launchd, plist

I have set up a `plist` file and loaded/started it with `launchd`. Whenever it is time for the script to run, I receive the following error in my console:

```
12/9/15 12:53:19.344 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (kjuvbot[742]) Service could not initialize: 14F27: xpcproxy + 13421 [1402][AD0301K4-D354-31AE-8BA7-B5KBECE64P0B]: 0x2
```

Does anyone have any idea why this error might occur? Here is my `.plist` file:

**kjuvbot.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>kjuvbot</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>python3</string>
        <string>/Users/me/workspace/Learning/src/kjuvbot.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>3600</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Does it by chance need `com.` in front of the filename?

Here are the permissions (I created the file as myself):

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff  427 Dec  9 19:28 kjuvbot.plist
```

Comment: Where is python3 ?

Comment: @Mark Ah ha! That is it. `launchd` is looking in `/usr/bin` for `python3`, isn't it? I changed the `python3` path to the full path, and it worked just fine. Feel free to post your answer below, and I will accept it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python3 is not in the path used by launchd which will be less that that in the terminal.

Try using the full path in the plist

e.g.

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/python3</string>
    <string>/Users/me/workspace/Learning/src/kjuvbot.py</string>
</array>
```